# SQL: How do you Sum a Sum column?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, amazon-athena, presto

My query returns the columns I need, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get another column that will return the sum of the: sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty column.  It's ok if it is listed for every row; I just want a way to not have to pull out the calculator and add up all of the sum(CAST(qty AS int)).

```
select sql1.item_code, sql1.supplier_so, sum(sql1.qty) Qty, sql1.dt
from
(SELECT supplier_so, item_code, sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty, dt FROM "table.name"
where
supplier_so = 'XXXXXXX'
group by supplier_so, item_code, dt
UNION
SELECT supplier_so, item_code, sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty, dt FROM "table.name2"
where
supplier_so = 'XXXXXXX'
and
dt < date '2021-06-01'
 group by supplier_so, item_code, dt
) sql1
group by supplier_so, item_code, dt
```

Comment: Check if your RDBMS supports [`ROLLUP`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-rollup/) feature.

Comment: It does seem to, but all it's doing is duplicating every single row

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [window function](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) for this:

```
SELECT 
   ..., 
   SUM(CAST(qty AS int)) OVER ()
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try this.

```
with sql1 as 
(SELECT supplier_so, item_code, sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty, dt FROM "table.name"
where
supplier_so = 'XXXXXXX'
group by supplier_so, item_code, dt
UNION
SELECT supplier_so, item_code, sum(CAST(qty AS int)) as qty, dt FROM "table.name2"
where
supplier_so = 'XXXXXXX'
and
dt < date '2021-06-01'
 group by supplier_so, item_code, dt
) 
select sql1.item_code, sql1.supplier_so, sql1.dt, sum(sql1.qty) over () from sql1;
```

Comment: So this does give me the column that I want, thank you!  However, it gets rid of the original qty column that shows all of the individual results that add up to the windowed sum(sql1.qty) over ()

Comment: If you want qty also in the output, you can add in the outer query. It should work. `select sql1.item_code, sql1.supplier_so, sql1.dt, sql1.qty, sum(sql1.qty) over () from sql1;`